# separate thread to prevent progress bar from 'freezing' in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I built a simplest progress bar which shows the progress of my png frame generation. Here is the process

```
BOOL myProc(HWND hwndParent, HINSTANCE hInst) {
    RECT rcClient;
    int cyVScroll;
    HWND hwndPB;
    DWORD cb;

    GetClientRect(hwndParent, &rcClient);
    cyVScroll = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVSCROLL);

    hwndPB = CreateWindowEx(0, PROGRESS_CLASS, (LPTSTR) NULL, 
                            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, rcClient.left, 
                            rcClient.bottom - cyVScroll, 
                            rcClient.right, cyVScroll, 
                            hwndParent, (HMENU) 0, hInst, NULL);
    int N = lastFrame;
    SendMessage(hwndPB, PBM_SETRANGE, 0, MAKELPARAM(0, N));
    SendMessage(hwndPB, PBM_SETSTEP, (WPARAM)1, 0);


    
    for (int i = 0; i < N + 1; i++) {
        int frame = create_pngInt(i);
        SendMessage(hwndPB, PBM_STEPIT, 0, 0);
        }

    DestroyWindow(hwndPB);
    DestroyWindow(hwndParent);
    return TRUE;

}
```

I want my window to host just this progress bar. When the loop in `myProc` is done, the host window should be destroyed.

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE PrevInst, LPSTR args, int ncmdshow) {
    WNDCLASSW wc = { 0 };
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"GenPng";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(0x00171c00);
    wc.hIcon = hIcon;

    if (!RegisterClassW(&wc))
        return -1;
    
    hMainWindow = CreateWindowW(L"GenPng", L"Generating pngs", WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        200,
        100, 300, 58, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    
    std::thread q(myProc, hMainWindow, hInst);
    MSG msg = { 0 };
    
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, the window `hMainWindow` is not destroyed (!) and the process `myProc` doesn't terminate by itself (after the loop in myProc is comlete).
It seems I don't understand something important.

I checked. If I don't create a separate thread but just run `myProc` in WinMain,  the window hosting the progress bar destroyed after  `myProc` returns. And this is precisely what I want. But the progress bar freezes after several seconds(. That is why I need a separate thread.

Following your remarks I modified the code like this:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE PrevInst, LPSTR args, int ncmdshow) {
    RECT rect;
    WNDCLASSW wc = { 0 };
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"GenPng";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(0x00171c00);
    wc.hIcon = hIcon;

    if (!RegisterClassW(&wc))
        return -1;

    hMainWindow = CreateWindowW(L"GenPng", L"Generating pngs", WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        200,
        100, 300, 58, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    SetWindowPos(hMainWindow, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);

    
    RECT rcClient;
    int cyVScroll;
    HWND hwndPB;
    DWORD cb;

    GetClientRect(hMainWindow, &rcClient);
    cyVScroll = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVSCROLL);

    hwndPB = CreateWindowEx(0, PROGRESS_CLASS, (LPTSTR)NULL,
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, rcClient.left,
        rcClient.bottom - cyVScroll,
        rcClient.right, cyVScroll,
        hMainWindow, (HMENU)0, hInst, NULL);
    int N = lastFrame;
    SendMessage(hwndPB, PBM_SETRANGE, 0, MAKELPARAM(0, N));
    SendMessage(hwndPB, PBM_SETSTEP, (WPARAM)1, 0);
    
    std::thread q(myProc, hMainWindow, hInst, hwndPB);

    MSG msg = { 0 };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, hMainWindow, NULL, NULL))
    {
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) {
            DestroyWindow(hMainWindow);
        }
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, I know that I haven't handled WM_QUIT event properly, and the whole thing is not destroyed. Could you please, elaborate just a little bit more and if the rest of the code is ok?

Comment: you need call `create_pngInt` in working thread (pass `hwndPB` to this thread as parameter)

Comment: You're probably better off leaving all the UI (including the progress bar) in the main thread and doing the CPU-intensive stuff in a background thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread which calls `CreateWindowEx` needs to be the one executing the `GetMessage` loop.

It won't get destroyed, as there is nothing processing the events and messages for it, including the `WM_DESTROY` message.

Keep your window creation in your main thread (and that thread only!), and use only `PostMessage` / `SendMessage` to send update events and finally a destroy message to the window owned by the main thread.

Ultimately handle a `WM_DESTROY` to your main window with `PostQuitMessage` and your are done.

In full:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE PrevInst, LPSTR args, int ncmdshow) {
    RECT rect;
    WNDCLASSW wc = { 0 };
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"GenPng";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    wc.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(0x00171c00);
    wc.hIcon = hIcon;

    if (!RegisterClassW(&wc))
        return -1;

    hMainWindow = CreateWindowW(
        L"GenPng", L"Generating pngs", WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        200,
        100, 300, 58, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
    );
    SetWindowPos(hMainWindow, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);


    RECT rcClient;
    int cyVScroll;
    HWND hwndPB;
    DWORD cb;

    GetClientRect(hMainWindow, &rcClient);
    cyVScroll = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVSCROLL);

    hwndPB = CreateWindowEx(
        0, PROGRESS_CLASS, (LPTSTR)NULL,
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, rcClient.left,
        rcClient.bottom - cyVScroll,
        rcClient.right, cyVScroll,
        hMainWindow, (HMENU)0, hInst, NULL
    );
    int N = lastFrame;
    SendMessage(hwndPB, PBM_SETRANGE, 0, MAKELPARAM(0, N));
    SendMessage(hwndPB, PBM_SETSTEP, (WPARAM)1, 0);

    std::thread q([hMainWindow, hInst, hwndPB, N]() {
        for (int i = 0; i < N + 1; i++) {
            SendMessage(hwndPB, PBM_STEPIT, 0, 0);
        }
        DestroyWindow(hMainWindow);
    });

    MSG msg = { 0 };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL))
    {
        if (msg.message == WM_DESTROY) {
            PostQuitMessage(0); 
        }
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    q.join();
    
    // Exit code from PostQuitMessage() is still in msg.param
    return msg.param;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ext3h! I'll give it a try immediately!

Comment: Dear Ext3h and RbMm, I just edited my main post. I think, I'm closer but still no success. Could you have a quick glance once more?

Comment: @YaroslavRodionov Did you call `PostQuitMessage` to trigger `WM_QUIT`? If not, do so. And you can't "handle" a `WM_QUIT` either, if sent correctly it causes `GetMessage` to return 0 and therefore to exit that loop.

You also forgot an `q.join()` at the end, after your loop.

Comment: Dear Ext3h, thank you for great help. Peculiarly, this window still survives. About WM_QUIT. In the CallBack function for hMainWindow I add                                  ```case WM_DESTROY:
  PostQuitMessage(0);
  break;```